# configuring dll from bin folder in existing project

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, dll

I got a c# solution developed by other developers.
This solution contains 30 projects and there is also git folder.
Every project has its `bin/` folder. I have web site and class libraries. All the code has poor quality: eg bin e obj folder are included in git.

I'm refactoring the code and reconfiguring also git. I don't want to include `bin/` folder in git, so I have created a dll folder in the root of every project containing libraries in the `bin/` folder. In this way also references in visual studio have not any warning.

Is it right? Are there other methods?

Second question: if I have a dll in the bin folder not present in the references, would I link that too? Or can I not consider it?

EDIT:

```
EG: in a class library (not in umbraco project):

 - bin/umbraco.dll
 - bin/umbraco.provider.dll
 - bin/umbraco.core.dll
 - bin/lucene.net.dll

In visual studio is referenced only:

 - umbraco.dll
```

So three ways:

1. Include bin folder in git and if i need to edit this project i will
   understand ho configure it;
2. Add a dll folder in the root (and in git), copy umbraco.dll in it. So references in
   visual studio are ok. But only umbraco.dll will be copied in bin
   folder. And the Others? Will i need them?
3. Add a dll folder in the root (and in git), copy all dll files in it.
   So references in visual studio are ok. And i take Others for future
   uses.

I choosed 3rd solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to include bin folder in git

Simply make sure you have a `.gitignore` which declares what you don't want:

```
bin/
```

That way, you don't even have to create a `dll` folder. Or if you do, you can ignore `bin/dll/` in that same `.gitignore` file (note the trailing '/' for ignoring *folders* in a `.gitignore`).

For CSharp projects, [gitignore.io proposes this .gitignore file](https://www.gitignore.io/api/csharp).

> If I ignore bin folder and you pull, the project will not compile!

git should always ignore (big) binaries: those dependencies, as commented by [Iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5993/iain), should comes from an artifact repository (like Nugget) or other *externa* referential: external to the git *source* repository, which is made to track the history of *sources* (text files), not to store binary dependencies.

But if you must, copy only the dll referenced by your project (`umbraco.dll`) in a versioned folder, and see if the project compile/works. Then add the missing one.
If you have to version those binary dependencies, it is best to try and version only the minimum amount of dlls.

Comment: I already know about gitignore. The problem is configuring correctly for the future. If i ignore bin folder and you pull, the project will not compile!

Comment: Recommend that the build shouldn't be dependent on anything in the 'bin' folder being checked into source control. External dependencies should be checked in elsewhere (perhaps a lib folder) or pulled in via NuGet. Inter-Project dependencies should use project references rather than referencing the generated DLL.

Comment: @Iain i agree but it's not a big project and there isn't any doc. I need only to get it, compile and edit. So, better include bin folder in git or save dll in a project subfolder?

Comment: @VonC thanks, but the discussion is about this particular case as i told in the previous answer

Comment: @Emanuele OK, then adding the dll folder to git should be a good enough solution for you.

Comment: @VonC ok :) but there are other dll files in the bin folder that are not referenced in the project (but can be dependent).. If i copy these dll files in the dll folder, they will not be included in bin...

Comment: @Emanuele so what is the issue? Having them both in bin and in dll folders?

Comment: I would not use bin for git using. Dll folder is ok but not solved if i have other dll files in bin folder not referenced directly by project.

Comment: @Emanuele Could you then add the dll folder to git, but ignore the bin folder for the rest? (or ignore `bin/*.dll` only if you want to add to git other files from the bin folder)

Comment: @Emanuele Then you could ignore those, since they are not referenced in your project.